# Remove value for a key on a PFObject

Tags: parse-platform, parse-ios-sdk

I am trying to update an object based on an edit object form that I provided to the user. Whenever the value for a field is set to "" It gives me an error **Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.** I have tried a couple of other things like `self.Asset!["Manufacturer"] = nil`, `self.Asset!["Manufacturer"] = ""` and `self.Asset!.remove(forKey: "Manufacturer")` All of these gave me the same error. Asset is a PFObject and Manufacturer is a key for that object. Below is the sample code for a field

```
        if(ManufacturerLabel.text != ""){
            self.Asset!["Manufacturer"] = ManufacturerLabel.text
        }else{
            self.Asset!.remove(forKey: "Manufacturer")
            //self.Asset!["Manufacturer"] = nil
        }
```

P.S. Please do not downvote it as I already checked the Parse Documents and other similar questions and nothing seems to work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you need to use NSNull. Try:

```swift
self.Asset!["Manufacturer"] = NSNull()
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much. Sorry I am new to NSNull and I did try NSNull but without (). The other thing i tried was NSNull.init() but non of these worked.